# How do you late-bind DatabaseTypeEnum values?

Tags: c#, enums, dao, late-binding

The `DatabaseTypeEnum` values are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/databasetypeenum-enumeration-dao).

How do you **late bind** the values?

At the moment I am passing literal integers:

- `64` for `dbVersion40`
- `128` for `dbVersion120`

This is the current code in context:

```
public bool CompactAccessDatabase(string strSourceDB, string strTargetDB, string strPassword, int iMode)
{
    try
    {
        // Get the DBEngine property
        dynamic dbEngine = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("DAO.DBEngine.120"));

        // Build the DB connection string
        string strDecryptedPassword = "";
        string strDBConnectionString = "";
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strPassword))
        {
            if (!DecryptDatabasePassword(strPassword, ref strDecryptedPassword))
            {
                SimpleLog.Log("DecryptDatabasePassword returned false");
            }
            strDBConnectionString = ";pwd=" + strDecryptedPassword;
        }

        int iOptions = 0;   // To Compact
        if (iMode == 1)     // To MDB
            iOptions = 64;  // DatabaseTypeEnum.dbVersion40 
        else if(iMode == 2) // To ACCDB
            iOptions = 128; // DatabaseTypeEnum.dbVersion120

        // Perform the compact
        dbEngine.CompactDatabase(strSourceDB, strTargetDB, "", iOptions, strDBConnectionString);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SimpleLog.Log(ex);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Is it possible to late bind the enum ids instead? Or is it best to use hard coded values?

Answer (score 0):

Just use cast it to int:

```
if (iMode == 1)     // To MDB
            iOptions = (int)DatabaseTypeEnum.dbVersion40 ;
        else if(iMode == 2) // To ACCDB
            iOptions = (int)DatabaseTypeEnum.dbVersion120;
```

https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/articles/convert-int-to-enum-in-csharp

Comment: But I am using late-binding. So `DatabaseTypeEnum` no an unknown enum ...

Comment: sorry, I didn't release you don't want to use any reference lib. In this case, yes, you have to use hard-coded values. or have your own version of that enum:
```
    public enum DatabaseTypeEnum
    {
        dbDecrypt = 4,
        dbEncrypt = 2,
        dbVersion10 = 1,
        dbVersion11 = 8,
        dbVersion120 = 128,
        dbVersion20 = 16,
        dbVersion30 = 32,
        dbVersion40 = 64
    }
```

Comment: Thought so. Thanks for confirming. If you want to re-work your answer then I can upvote and accept it, and we can delete these comments.